Springboot + Spring Cloud Stream + Pulsar Binder startup failed
We want to use Pulsar binder to configure Pulsar consumer that produces on Kafka with usage of multibinder approach (https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/reference/spring-cloud-stream/multiple-binders.html). Unfortunately, the following configuration causes Springboot startup failure with the error: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.pulsar.core.PulsarAdministration.
      binders:
        kafka:
          type: kafka
          (...)
        pulsar:
          type: pulsar
          environment:
            spring:
              cloud:
                stream:
                  pulsar:
                    binder:
                      config:
                        serviceUrl: pulsar://localhost:6650
                        adminUrl: http://localhost:8080

After deleting the environment property from pulsar binder, everything is fine, but it disables the possibility of additional configuration at this level. Is this a bug?
We expect to be able to use multibinder approach for the processor with Pulsar as input and Kafka as output with possibility of usage pulsar biner configuration.

Thanks for the report Dagmara. This sounds like a bug. I have created https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/3013. Do you mind adding the version of Spring Boot and Spring Cloud Stream that you are using to that issue?

Springboot 3.3.2 + spring-cloud-stream 4.1.2, we tried also Springboot 3.2, 3.1 and 3.0, the same behaviour every time.
